# Which subspaces of $\ell_p^n$ are isometric?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces

This question is similar to the one asked here:

[Extending linear isometries from subspaces of $\ell_p^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292008/extending-linear-isometries-from-subspaces-of-ell-pn)

Let $p$ be an even integer. Let $X,Y$ be subspaces of $\ell_p^n$, and let $U : X \to Y$ be a linear isometry. For which pairs $(X,Y)$ is this possible?

Clearly, if $X$ is the span of the vectors $x_1,\cdots,x_k$, then $Y$ could be any subspace spanned by the vectors $P x_1, \cdots, P x_k$, where $P$ is a generalised permutation matrix (a permutation matrix that allows $-1$ where a $1$ should be). This is because such matrices are isometries of the entire space $\ell_p^n$.

For $p \in [1,\infty]$, $p \not = 2 \mathbb{N}$, one can completely characterise these pairs of isometric subspaces (this result is similar to the Plotkin-Rudin Theorem). For "almost every" subspace $X$, the only subspaces $Y$ such that there exists a map $U : X \to Y$ that preserves norm are the "obvious" subspaces mentioned above.

I would like to know which subspace pairs are isometric when $p$ is an even integer.